# Qual é a diferença entre ASC ou DESC em índices clusterizados?

Tags: sql-server, índices

Quando eu vou criar um índice não *clusterizado* no SQL SERVER, aparece no SSMS a opção de escolher se a opção "Colunas" é `ASC` ou `DESC`, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Indice clusterizado com valor ASC]

Geralmente, usa-se `ASC` ou `DESC` para ordenação dos resultados da tabela, mas no caso do índice *clusterizado* eu não entendo muito bem o significado.

Eu gostaria de saber o seguinte:

- Qual é a diferença entre `ASC` e `DESC` no caso da definição de um índice *clusterizado*?
- Definir `ASC` ou `DESC` acarreta em alguma diferença notória de performance ou outra coisa?
- Quando eu deveria usar um e outro? No caso, posso criar um índice *clusterizado* `ASC` e outro `DESC` para a mesma coluna?

Comment: Acredito que para iniciar com a tabela normal (asc) ou "de ponta-cabeça" (desc) dependendo se for ter uma consulta padrão por exemplo, que geralmente são nos primeiros registros, ou últimos... (acompanhando) +1

Comment: @rbz quer dizer que se eu colocar `ORDER BY coluna_com_o_indice_clusterizado_com_DESC` então os resultados serão `DESC`, mesmo sem eu ter definido isso no `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Não. Por exemplo: Você tem o "nunca pare" do pedágio. Ele tem um código referente sua placa. Imagina o quanto tem que ser rápido o sistema para fazer a consulta e te liberar enquanto você passa a 40 km/h lá certo!?... Então aí entra o índice, a grosso modo, um auxiliar de consulta interno do BD. Até sei que já sabe tudo. Então vamos supor que você está viajando, então lá no BD do "nunca pare", você estaria no final da tabela "consultas_liberacao". Vamos supor que o sistema deles é inteligente, e sempre consulta essa tabela quando você passa para uma liberação. [...]

Comment: [...] mesmo que sua tabela tenha índices, ela pode "começar a ler" do início para o fim (asc), ou do fim para o início (desc), como se você fizesse um select e estivesse lendo os resultados. Você faz um select e sabe que o que você busca geralmente está no final, então usa (desc) para "iniciar" sua leitura... basicamente isso.

Comment: A ideia é que: mesmo com índices, ele segue uma sequência. É melhor começar pelo início ou pelo fim!? ... como eu só conversei 1x sobre isso, a um bom tempo, então não tenho certeza, por isso achei melhor comentar somente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chupei de [uma resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382500/221800):

Se você costuma fazer muito mais buscas ao contrário (e isto não é comum) pode ser mais rápido se usar o `DESC` na edição do SQL Server que suporta buscas paralelizadas, já que somente buscas sequenciais para frente podem ser paralelizadas. Então se tiver um `ASC` e mandar consultar `DESC`, não tem paralelização (hoje).

[image: Mostrando o plano de execução]

Também falam em fragmentação do índice. De fato pode ser mais complicado fazer *append* no índice em ordem contrária. Um dos motivos de se usar o índice *clusterizado* é justamente ter a facilidade de ir adicionando de forma natural.

Portanto eu evitaria `DESC` *clusterizado* se fará muito *append* e se não utilizar quase exclusivamente para ler ao contrário.

Eu não gosto muito dos mecanismos de banco de dados porque eles acabam te forçando certas coisas. Prefiro usá-los só como *storage* e deixar fazer o que eu quiser, o que pode dar mais flexibilidade de como lidar om isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).